# Automating Payments From Server Side To User

Tags: metamask, payments

To all Ethereum Developers,

I am currently working on a school project where my application involves users spinning a lucky wheel and getting rewarded with Ethereum. However, I am stuck with the implementation regarding how to automate the transfer of Ethereum from the developer side to the user end (Ie, there is no need for me/the developer to approve every transaction). I am currently using MetaMask and JS. I am relatively new to this space and would appreciate any comments! Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Porsche Tan
Singapore

Answer (score 1):

### Gelato

You can automate payments with a tool like [Gelato Ops](https://app.gelato.network/#/).

[image: Gelato Ops]

### Sablier

As a side note though, why limit yourself to discrete payments? With smart contracts, we can easily enable continuous, by-the-second payments. I happen to be one of the founders of [Sablier](https://sablier.com), an Ethereum-based protocol which enables token streaming.

[image: Sablier Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can use cron-job for that or a new thing I researched on is Gelato network, which basically allows you to run a contract on a specific date and time.

What you could do, Is that run the function every 1 or 5 mins and check a specific condition if its true then transact those funds else do nothing. Hope you found what you were looking for.